# xml parsing error special characters

Tags: python, xml

I have following xml that I want to parse with `xml.dom.minidom` module

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RootTag>
         <InnerTag>
              <MyValue>"< here is special char."</MyValue>
         </InnerTag>
 </RootTag>
```

I have following snippet for parsing above xml

```
import xml.dom.minidom
xml.dom.minidom.parse('input_xml')
```

But I get following error:

```
     parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4, column 26
```

Above error occurs only when I provide '&' or '<' provided in MyValue tags

So,

How to resolve this issue?
I am not wishing to change my XML by using escape sequence `&lt;` etc..
and I want to use "" (quotes)

Comment: To Down voters .. Please  mention comments

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're not going to be able to use an XML parser on XML that is not well-formed. You might not wish to escape `&` or `<`, but you don't have a choice other than a `CDATA` section (see eclaird's answer below for an example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not well-formed XML. `<` is not allowed in XML anywhere else other than the tags. Your data needs to be wrapped in CDATA or escaped as `&lt;`

```
<![CDATA[< here is special char.]]>
```